# Passing type argument to Eiffel method

Tags: generics, eiffel

I would like to write a cast method in Eiffel which takes 'the type to cast to' as a type parameter.  Is there a way to pass a type into a method in Eiffel.

The only alternative I can think of is to create a new class for the conversion.  Something like:

```
class
   CAST [G, H]

feature

   cast (in: LIST [G]): LIST [H]
      do
         -- cast code here
      end
```

Is there a better way to do this in Eiffel.  In C# I can specify that a method takes type parameters separate from the class type parameters.  Is there a similar feature in Eiffel?

I am using EiffelStudio 6.6.8.3873 GPL.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the C#, so we know what you are trying to do. A minimal example and and in context would be good.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to try to answer it, could you give some more code or/and use sample please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to have generic methods, where the return type is determined by a passed parameter in Eiffel. Sorry. 
I ran into the same issue. You will have return a common superclass and use an assignment attempts to get a reference to the returned object with the right type.